# sonar-csharp cannot pass tests

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I build sonar-csharp plugin in accordance with　https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-csharp/blob/master/docs/contributing-plugin.md

but code cannot pass the test and output error like below.

```
Results :

Tests in error:
  CSharpSonarRulesDefinitionTest.test:38 ▒▒ NullPointer
  CSharpSonarWayProfileTest.test:39 ▒▒ NullPointer

Tests run: 22, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] SonarC# parent ..................................... SUCCESS [  2.796 s]
[INFO] SonarQube .NET Tests Library ....................... SUCCESS [  7.697 s]
[INFO] SonarSource :: .NET :: Shared library .............. SUCCESS [  9.005 s]
[INFO] SonarC# ............................................ FAILURE [  4.419 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 25.035 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-11-30T13:08:36+09:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 42M/420M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project sonar-csharp-plugin: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\sonar-csharp\sonar-csharp-plugin\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] 
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :sonar-csharp-plugin
```

Comment: We will likely need to see some code on the failing sections?

Comment: Could you share which of the 2 commands described in the doc you have been using? Also could you share the commit hashcode you are using?

Comment: I used first command(use local analyzer) and commit hashcode is 5f1eb92b1ea27181bb85822765d06c5003871a86